# Android studio builds the app fine but it crashes on emulator/ device

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

So basically everything was fine until I messed around implementing admob, now Android studio installs the app fine with no errors etc but the app crashes immediately on both the emulator and physical device.

This is from the Error log in logcat, if you need the code etc then just ask and I'll provide whatever is needed! All I know is it's doing my head in!!

```
2020-07-10 20:50:11.880 643-2806/system_process E/system_server: Invalid class loader spec: =UnsupportedClassLoaderContext=
2020-07-10 20:50:11.881 643-2806/system_process E/PackageDexUsage: Unsupported context?
2020-07-10 21:16:49.761 643-715/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2020-07-10 21:41:59.514 643-1496/system_process E/system_server: Invalid class loader spec: =UnsupportedClassLoaderContext=
2020-07-10 21:41:59.514 643-1496/system_process E/PackageDexUsage: Unsupported context?
2020-07-10 21:41:59.953 643-1496/system_process E/system_server: Invalid class loader spec: =UnsupportedClassLoaderContext=
2020-07-10 21:41:59.953 643-1496/system_process E/PackageDexUsage: Unsupported context?
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/crash#reading_a_stack_trace

Comment: please watch youtube vids for admob in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the code in the XML was below the  somehow I managed to miss it for about 6 hours!!!